# Will android odex improve app or system launch speed?

Tags: android

When we install an apk on Android,system will get the classes.dex out of the apk file,optimize it with dexopt tool and generate another .dex file stored in /data/dalvik-cache.

Now if we use dexopt-wrappter tool to optimize the apk first to generate the odex file,and then delete the classes.dex from apk file,and then push the apk file(without classes.dex) and the odex file into /data/app.

Will the second way be faster than the first way when launching this app?
If all apks in this system have been optimized with the second way,will it be faster when launching the system?

I know the .dex files in /data/dalvik-cache/ are the same as files generating by the second way.I just wonder that will it be faster when launching with the second way.Because original Android system apps have been all optimized with the second way.